# How to configure StandardJS?

Tags: javascript, standards, eslint, lint, standardjs

One of the main features of [StandardJS](https://standardjs.com/) is that it doesn't require configuration.

The problem is that I want to configure it. I don't want to put:

```
/* eslint-env mocha */
```

...in every test file. I want to configure StandardJS to treat everything in the test directory as mocha tests.

I've found in the [README](https://standardjs.com/#what-about-mocha-jasmine-qunit-etc) that some configuration is possible, e.g.:

```
{
  "standard": {
    "globals": [ "myVar1", "myVar2" ]
  }
}
```

...but I'm struggling to find more comprehensive documentation about the configuration options. Is it possible to configure StandardJS to treat files in different directories differently?

Comment: https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/master/options.js hmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: This vscode plugin allows the setting to be modified, maybe look for how they do it https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenxsan.vscode-standardjs

Answer (score 8):

You have a couple of options to **try out and see** what works for your specific project *depending on the recent implementation of StandardJS*.

---

## Define your own globals

in **package.json**:

```
"standard": {
  "globals": [
    "describe",
    "before",
    "after",
    "beforeEach",
    "afterEach",
    "it",
    "assert"
  ]
}
```

or in **.eslintrc**:

```
{
  "globals": {
    "describe": false,
    "before": false,
    "after": false,
    "beforeEach": false,
    "afterEach": false,
    "it": false,
    "assert": false
  }
}
```

[More on ESLint's configuration.](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals)

---

## Define an environment

in **package.json**:

```
"standard": {
  "env": {
    "mocha": true
  }
}
```

or in **.eslintrc**:

```
{
  "env": {
    "mocha": true
  }
}
```

#### [**Check out currently available environments**](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)

---

## Run StandardJS as an NPM script with the environment specified

in **package.json**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "standard --env mocha"
  }
}
```

---

## Use a plugin

after installing the plugin (e.g. [**eslint-plugin-mocha**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-mocha))

in **package.json**:

```
"standard": {
  "plugins": [
    "mocha"
  ]
}
```

or in **.eslintrc**:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "mocha"
  ]
}
```

---

## Create your own, customized rules based on StandardJS

[**Check out this repository**](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard). The quick rundown:

Install with:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-standard eslint-plugin-promise eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-node
```

Then create a **.eslintrc** file by extending StandardJS and start to fill with your own rules:

```
{
  "extends": "standard"
}
```

Since **StandardJS uses ESLint under the hood**, you can pretty much configure it however you want it [**using ESLint's documentation**](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring).

Comment: I tried to do that, but it doesn't pick up my `.eslintrc.json`. Are you saying that anything I can configure in a `.eslintrc` file would work in the standard configuration in `package.json`?

Comment: StandardJS definitely recommends you to put your **per-project configurations into the project's package.json**, [so try that first](https://standardjs.com/#i-use-a-library-that-pollutes-the-global-namespace-how-do-i-prevent-variable-is-not-defined-errors). Other, than that, try creating a **.eslintrc** *(without any extension)* **OR** **eslintrc.json** *(without leading dot)* in your project's root directory and check, whether StandardJS picks it up. If not, looks like their current implementation prefers the **package.json** option.

Comment: If none of the above works, check out [**this repository**](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard) and try its solution to configure StandardJS. Please, try these options out and get back to me about what solution worked for you.

Comment: That's what I did. I simply configured eslint to use the standard configuration, so that I can have different linting rules for my tests. However, that doesn't answer my question.